# Bidirectional @OneToOne Spring Data JPA, Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I am using **`Bidirectional @OneToOne`** from [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional). I have created an identical model for the test.

I can't get Phone via PhoneDetails. I get an error - **`Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.example.model.Phone#1] - no Session`**.

I've tried many options and it doesn't work.

Please tell me how to get the Phone correctly? I sit all day trying to do this. I did not find any options on the Internet, so I ask here.

**`Phone.java`**

```
    @Entity(name = "Phone")
    public class Phone {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "`number`")
        private String number;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "phone",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true,
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

        private PhoneDetails details;

        public Phone() {
        }

        public Phone(String number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        // Getters and setters are omitted for brevity

        public void addDetails(PhoneDetails details) {
            details.setPhone( this );
            this.details = details;
        }

        public void removeDetails() {
            if ( details != null ) {
                details.setPhone( null );
                this.details = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**`PhoneDetails.java`**

```
    @Entity(name = "PhoneDetails")
    public class PhoneDetails {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        private String provider;

        private String technology;

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id")
        private Phone phone;

        public PhoneDetails() {
        }

        public PhoneDetails(String provider, String technology) {
            this.provider = provider;
            this.technology = technology;
        }


        // Getters and setters are omitted for brevity

    }
```

**`LifecycleController.java`**

```
    @Controller
    public class LifecycleController {


        @Autowired
        ServiceJpa serviceJpa;


        @GetMapping(value = "/savePhoneAndPhoneDetails")
        public String savePersonAddress () {

            Phone phone = new Phone( "123-456-7890" );
            PhoneDetails details = new PhoneDetails( "T-Mobile", "GSM" );

            phone.addDetails( details );
            serviceJpa.savPhone( phone );


            return "/savePhoneAndPhoneDetails";
        }



        @GetMapping(value = "/getPhone")
        public String addPersonAddress () {


            PhoneDetails address = serviceJpa.findPhoneDetailsById(2L).orElseThrow();
            Phone phone = address.getPhone();

            /* 
               An error appears here -
               could not initialize proxy
               [com.example.model.Phone#1] - no Session
            */
            System.out.println(phone.getNumber());


            return "/getPhone";
        }

    }
```

**`ServiceJpa.java`**

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class ServiceJpa {



        @Autowired
        PhoneJpa phoneJpa;

        @Autowired
        PhoneDetailsJpa phoneDetailsJpa;


        @Transactional
        public void savPhone(Phone phone) {
            phoneJpa.save(phone);
        }


        @Transactional
        public Optional<PhoneDetails> findPhoneDetailsById(Long id) {
            return phoneDetailsJpa.findById(id);
        }


    }
```

**interface** **`PhoneJpa.java`**

```
    @Repository
    public interface PhoneJpa extends JpaRepository<Phone, Long> {
        
    }
```

**interface** **`PhoneDetailsJpa.java`**

```
    @Repository
    public interface PhoneDetailsJpa extends JpaRepository<PhoneDetails, Long> {

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Make your ServiceJpa transactional by adding the annotation @Transactional

Comment: I did it. It does not help.

Comment: Please, add your ServiceJpa code to the question

Comment: I added. Look please.

Comment: You should not access entity details outside transaction bounds. Well, as a quick and dirty hack you may put @Transaction on Controller level. The correct solution is to map entity to DTO representation, consider my article https://github.com/slobodator/hibernate-probe#entity-and-dto

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andriy's comment with a slight addition of "You should not access [lazily loaded] entity details outside transaction bounds". But, for starters, is there some reason you want the OneToOne to be FetchType.LAZY to begin with? If you changed it to EAGER, your "lazy" problem would be resolved by virtue of it no longer being a lazy reference but being a real hydrated object.

If that is not the exact route you want to take, there are a dozen ways to EAGERLY fetch things in general and frankly too many to present a single solution here as best/ideal. As your code exists, since all the dereferencing (for now) is happening inside your Controller, then Andriy's suggestion to add @Transaction to the Controller may suffice in that it will be lazily fetched when you need it.

But in the future, if you have Lazy elements in a POJO that get returned to the stack higher than the controller, say, just before they are serialized to JSON for example, then even the CONTROLLER's @Transactional wouldn't be "high" enough in the stack and you'll end up with the same Lazy init problem..

Also, by having it be Lazy and then dereferencing it elsewhere, you're guaranteeing two trips to the Database. With proper FETCH/JOIN eager loads, you would limit that to one, which can be another performance benefit.

So either way, you're back to the real problem at hand.. looking for ways to ensure your operations occur ENTIRELY inside a Transaction boundary *OR* having to completely hydrate the object so no "Lazy" danglers get dereferenced outside of that.. i.e. by making them eager or by force-initializing any potential Lazy proxies/collections.